# Rabbit MQ synchronous Send and receive in multithreaded application

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a multithreaded spring application, where I am creating the topic exchange, declaring queues, binding them with routing key. Send and receive messages synchronously. I am able to send the message over to topic exchange and see messages being published to queues with routingKey.

However while receiving the message, I am seeing the consumers getting registered  for the queue in every time iteration and not getting deregistered. I am creating QueueingConsumer for receiving the message, probably there might be another way to do the same, please let me know. Below is the snippet for receiveMessage method.

```
public ObjectMessage receiveMessage(final String readQueue, final UUID correlationId, final boolean isBroadcastMessage, final int readTimeout, final int readAttempts) 
{
    this.configurationLock.lock();
    this.transmissionSemaphore.release(1);
    this.configurationLock.unlock();
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < readAttempts; i++)
        {
            ObjectMessage returnValue = null;
            try
            {
                returnValue = this.receiveMessage(readQueue, correlationId, isBroadcastMessage, readTimeout);
            }
            catch (final Exception e)
            {
                logger.error(e);
            }
            if (returnValue != null)
            {
                logger.warn("Message received from queue - " + readQueue);
                return returnValue;
            }
        }
        if (correlationId != null)
        {
            throw new MessageNotFoundException(correlationId);
        }
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            this.transmissionSemaphore.acquire(1);
        }
        catch (final InterruptedException e)
        {
            Thread.interrupted();
        }
    }
}


private ObjectMessage receiveMessage(final String routingKey, final UUID correlationId, final boolean isBroadcastMessage, final int readTimeout) throws Exception
{
    logger.debug("receiveMessage - routingKey:" + routingKey + ",correlationId:" + correlationId + ",isBroadcastMessage:" + isBroadcastMessage + ",readTimeout:"
            + readTimeout);
    this.configurationLock.lock();
    this.transmissionSemaphore.release(1);
    this.configurationLock.unlock();

    Connection connection = null;
    Channel channel = null;
    QueueingConsumer consumer = null;
    try
    {
        // Binding the topic exchange with queue using routing key
        final String queueName = "clientConfigurationQueue";
        final CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = this.getCachingConnectionFactory(routingKey);
        if (isBroadcastMessage)
        {
            this.declareTopicAmqpInfrastructure(cachingConnectionFactory, routingKey, queueName);
        }
        QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery;

        connection = cachingConnectionFactory.createConnection();
        channel = connection.createChannel(false);

        consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);

        if (correlationId == null)
        {
            channel.basicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);
            delivery = consumer.nextDelivery(readTimeout);
        }
        else
        {
            channel.basicConsume(queueName, false, consumer);
            while (true)
            {
                delivery = consumer.nextDelivery(readTimeout);
                if (delivery != null)
                {
                    final String correlationId = delivery.getProperties().getCorrelationId();

                    if (correlationId.equals(correlationId))
                    {
                        channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        channel.basicNack(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false, true);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        ObjectMessage objectMessage = null;
        if (delivery != null)
        {
            logger.debug("Message received with correlationId - " + delivery.getProperties().getCorrelationId() + " for queue - " + queueName);
            logger.debug("Message received with Body - " + SerializationUtils.deserialize(delivery.getBody()));
            objectMessage = new ObjectMessage();
            objectMessage.setCorrelationId(delivery.getProperties().getCorrelationId());
            objectMessage.setMessage(delivery.getBody());
        }
        else
        {
            logger.debug("Message not received from queueName - " + queueName);
        }

        return objectMessage;
    }
    catch (final IOException | ShutdownSignalException | ConsumerCancelledException | InterruptedException e)
    {
        logger.error("Unable to receive message - " + e);
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            this.transmissionSemaphore.acquire(1);
        }
        catch (final InterruptedException e)
        {
            Thread.interrupted();
        }

        try
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.close();
            }

            if (channel != null)
            {
                channel.close();
            }
        }
        catch (final Exception ignore)
        {

        }
    }
}

private void declareTopicAmqpInfrastructure(final CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory, final String routingKey, String queueName)
{
    final Connection connection = cachingConnectionFactory.createConnection();
    final Channel channel = connection.createChannel(false);
    try
    {
        channel.exchangeDeclare("topicExchange", ExchangeTypes.TOPIC, true, false, null);
        channel.queueDeclare(queueName, true, false, false, null);
        channel.queueBind(queueName, "topicExchange", routingKey);
    }
    catch (final IOException e)
    {
        logger.error("Unable to declare rabbit queue, exchange and binding - " + e);
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.close();
        try
        {
            channel.close();
        }
        catch (final IOException ignore)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are describing makes no sense to me; please provide much more detail (stack trace etc). If you can post a sample app that reproduces it (e.g. on Gist), that would be even better.

Comment: Provided more details with sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your edits, you have completely changed your question; your original question said you were hung in `createConnection()`. If you are using Spring AMQP, why don't you use its higher level abstractions? You are never canceling your consumers - you need to keep track of the consumerTag returned by `basicConsume` and cancel it with `basicCancel` when you are finished.

Comment: Sorry about changing the question completely, as I had some mess created out of it with little understanding the AMQP concepts related to topic and fanout exchange.

By higher level abstractions, do you mean using RabbitTemplate send and receive methods?

Comment: Yes, and the message listener container for async receive.

Comment: The consumers list dropped immediately. Thank you very much Gary. You have been a great mentor.

Comment: I have already implemented the system using asynchronous  SimpleMessageListenerContainer and everything is working great. Now I want to use synchronous send and receive to see the performance difference with pros / cons of both approaches for our system.